# Manage changes in a DateTimerPicker control WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, command, datetimepicker

I'm using a DateTimePicker in my WPF MVVC application. It looks like this:

```
<Label Content="Date: "/>
<xctk:DateTimePicker 
  Value="{Binding Example.FirstDate, 
    Mode=TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    Converter={StaticResource validDateConverter}}"
      Format="Custom" 
      FormatString="{}dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
</xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

What I'd like to do now is to be aware of the changes in the date.
So that if an user changes the date I'm able to do some things in the ViewModel. It has to be in the ViewModel NOT in the codebehind.
(I say this because an Event is not an option).

My idea was to use a Command or a Trigger but it doesn't allow me (it is not an option).
Could somebody help me out please? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The `FirstDate` property will get set when the date is changed so you could handle your logic in the setter of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example using a CheckBox but it's the same thing for a DateTimePicker control:
You will need to add a reference like so:

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Then you can do this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Content="{Binding Path=Item.Description}">

    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding DataContext.AddUserPermissionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Item.Id}" />
        </b:EventTrigger>

        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveUserPermissionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Item.Id}" />
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

As you can see it hooks to the event "Checked" in this case, and then invokes a command. So you can do the same with whatever control and event you need to fire a command from.